# The right way to use CTE

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I'm new to Common Table Expressions and I think I need  to use one in order to achieve what I require.

If I run the following script  -

```
select MainRentAccountReference,EffectiveFromDate,CollectionDay,NumberOfCollections,DirectDebitTotalOverrideAmount 
from DirectDebitApportionment
where id = 1
```

It would give me the below results - 
[image]

So for each row that my CTE would return- for each unique MainRentAccountReference - I would want to create a row based on the following criteria.

3 Rows as the NumberOfCollections is set to 3
The following dates on each row - 01/05/18, 01/06/18, 01/07/18 so basically plus one month.
However is the CollectionDate was set to say 10, then I would want the 3 dates to be   10/05/18, 10/06/18, 10/07/18 
Finally each row to have a value of DirectDebitTotalOverrideAmount divided by number of NumberOfCollections.

I've been playing about with this and can get no where near the results I'm trying to achieve. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No you don't need a CTE at all. You just need to join this one row table with a three row table to get three rows. The three row table would be some kind of tally table that you could use `between collectionday and numberofcollections` on. So... step one: create a tally table - a table has a column that counts from 1 to a big number (say 1000)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a recursive CTE

```
with t as (
      select *
      from DirectDebitApportionment
      where id = 1
     ),
     cte as (
      select . . ., , 1 as collection, DirectDebitTotalOverrideAmount / NumberOfCollections as collection_amount
      from t
      union all
      select . . ., , collection + 1, DirectDebitTotalOverrideAmount / NumberOfCollections as collection_amount
      from cte
      where collection < NumberOfCollections
     )
select . . .
from cte;
```

In some dialects of SQL, you need the `recursive` keyword.

Also, this can also be accomplished using a `numbers` table -- and that can be more efficient than the recursive CTE (although recursive CTEs often perform surprisingly well).

Comment: This has got me pretty much where I need to be - All I am now trying to work out is that at the moment all the EffectiveFromDates are falling on the first of the month as it's basing it on the EffectiveFromDate which is 01/05/18...however if the CollectionDay field is 10 what I would want it to do is start the EffectiveFromDates in the CTE from the 10/05/18. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick based on the pointers that Gordon gave me -

```
  with t as (
      select MainRentAccountReference,EffectiveFromDate,CollectionDay,NumberOfCollections,DirectDebitTotalOverrideAmount 
      from DirectDebitApportionment
      where id = 1
     ),
     cte as (
      select 1 as collection
      ,t.MainRentAccountReference
      ,convert(decimal(18,2),DirectDebitTotalOverrideAmount / NumberOfCollections) as collection_amount
      ,NumberOfCollections
      ,convert(datetime,DATEFROMPARTS ( DATEPART(YEAR,EffectiveFromDate), DATEPART(MONTH,EffectiveFromDate), CollectionDay )) AS EffectiveFromDate
      ,CollectionDay

      from t
      union all
      select collection + 1,MainRentAccountReference,collection_amount,NumberOfCollections,DATEADD(M,1,EffectiveFromDate),CollectionDay
     from cte
     where collection < cte.NumberOfCollections
     )
select *
from cte
Order by MainRentAccountReference,collection
;
```

Gives me the following results -

[image]